# Multi-file C++ compilation

Tags: c++

(hopefully) quick question that I can't find the answer to:

I have been given a brief assignment in C++. We are to write a 3-file program. There will be a function file, a header file, and a driver file. Here's what I've got so far:

Header (test.h):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

int foo (int bar);

#endif
```

Function (test.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;

int foo (int bar){
    bar++;
}
```

Driver (drive.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x = foo(2);
    cout << x << endl;
    return x;
}
```

When I try to compile drive.cpp, I get the following error:

```
drive.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `foo(int)'
```

So...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `#include <test.h>` should probably be `#include "test.h"`

Comment: For the love of Stroustrup, don't use `using namespace ...` in a header.

Comment: test.h and test.cpp have no reason to `#include <iostream>`.

Answer (score 4):

For a small project like this, simply compile all .cpp files at once:

```
g++ main.cpp driver.cpp
```

For a larger project, you separate the compile and link steps:

compile:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -c driver.cpp -o driver.o
```

link:

```
g++ main.o driver.o
```

Or rather, you'd have a makefile or IDE do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

In drive.cpp, instead of

```
#include <test.h>
```

make it

```
#include "test.h"
```

This is the variant of `#include` syntax that is used for header files of your own program (not system header files).  When you use this version the preprocessor searches for include files in the following order:

- In the same directory as the file that contains the #include statement.
- In the directories of any previously opened include files in the reverse order in which they were opened. The search starts from the directory of the include file that was opened last and continues through the directory of the include file that was opened first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do one of two things:

Compile all the files at once

```
# replace 'driver.exe' with what you want your executable called
g++ -Wall -ggdb -o driver.exe main.cpp driver.cpp
```

Compile all the files to object files and then link the object files:

```
# again, replace 'driver.exe' with what you want your executable called
g++ -Wall -ggdb -o main.o -c main.cpp
g++ -Wall -ggdb -o driver.o -c driver.cpp
g++ -Wall -ggdb -o driver.exe main.o driver.o
```

As a side note, you should probably change

```
#include <test.h>
```

to

```
#include "test.h"
```

and putting "using namespace std;" in a header file is going to cause you copious grief later on.

Answer (score 1):

in `test.cpp`, change the return line to this:

```
return bar++;
```